# How to find the Iphone speed and Gravity values?

Tags: iphone

I am developing one application,In that i want speed of the iPhone and gravity values.
For gravity, i need x,y,z axis values So How to find that values

Please send me the some post regarding that one

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this
 http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMMotionManager

Comment: Send me is there any examples

Comment: Added required code as second answer, because of my company policy  cant give you the whole application....

Comment: Thank u sir.But i dont want whole application.I want code for how to calculate speed by using x,y,z values.Please sir

Answer (score 0):

Add the CoreMotion.framework to your project, then import:

```
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
```

then start a sample app and add this as a button action...

```
- (IBAction) startUserMotion:(id)sender {

    CMMotionManager *motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *motionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    

    motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.50;
    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.50;
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.50; 
    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^ (CMDeviceMotion *devMotion, NSError *error)
     {  
         NSMutableDictionary *motionDetails = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        // CMAttitude *currentAttitude = devMotion.attitude;
         CMRotationRate rotation = devMotion.rotationRate;
         CMAcceleration acceleration = devMotion.userAcceleration;
         [motionDetails setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:acceleration.x] forKey:@"AccelerationX"];
         [motionDetails setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:acceleration.y] forKey:@"AccelerationY"];
         [motionDetails setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:acceleration.z] forKey:@"AccelerationZ"];

         [motionDetails setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:rotation.x] forKey:@"RotationX"];
         [motionDetails setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:rotation.y] forKey:@"RotationY"];
         [motionDetails setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:rotation.z] forKey:@"RotationZ"];
         [motionArray addObject:motionDetails];
         [motionDetails release];
     }   ];
}
```

Comment: What is the use of this one.We calculate the acceleration and rotation values.And placed in one array.Please tell me because iam new for this one.

Comment: It's just a sample code to show how can you get acceleration and gyro values from iphone, in this we get relative values..

Comment: K.Thanks.One small doubt.How to get the iphone version programatically?